# Beat detection algorithm implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm, multithreading, audio, signal-processing

What is the quality of the code I've written? Is it easy to read or is it a low-quality piece of code? Also, is there any way I can improve the algorithm itself (beside changing C parameters)?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Un4seen.Bass;
using Un4seen.BassWasapi;

namespace Szab.BeatDetector
{
public enum SensivityLevel
{
    VERY_LOW = 120,
    LOW = 110,
    NORMAL = 100,
    HIGH = 80,
    VERY_HIGH = 70
};

public sealed class SpectrumBeatDetector
{
    #region Fields

    // Constants
    private const int BANDS = 10;
    private const int HISTORY = 50;

    // Events
    public delegate void BeatDetectedHandler(byte Value);
    private event BeatDetectedHandler OnDetected;

    // Threading
    private Thread _AnalysisThread;

    // BASS Process
    private WASAPIPROC _WasapiProcess = new WASAPIPROC(SpectrumBeatDetector.Process);

    // Analysis settings
    private int _SamplingRate;
    private int _DeviceCode;
    private SensivityLevel _BASSSensivity;
    private SensivityLevel _MIDSSensivity;

    // Analysis data
    private float[] _FFTData = new float[4096];
    private double[,] _History = new double[BANDS, HISTORY];

    #endregion

    #region Setup methods

    public SpectrumBeatDetector(int DeviceCode, int SamplingRate = 44100, SensivityLevel BASSSensivity = SensivityLevel.NORMAL, SensivityLevel MIDSSensivity = SensivityLevel.NORMAL)
    {
        _SamplingRate = SamplingRate;
        _BASSSensivity = BASSSensivity;
        _MIDSSensivity = MIDSSensivity;
        _DeviceCode = DeviceCode;
        Init();
    }

    // BASS initialization method
    private void Init()
    {
        bool result = false;

        // Initialize BASS on default device
        result = Bass.BASS_Init(0, _SamplingRate, BASSInit.BASS_DEVICE_DEFAULT, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (!result)
        {
            throw new BassInitException(Bass.BASS_ErrorGetCode().ToString());
        }

        // Initialize WASAPI
        result = BassWasapi.BASS_WASAPI_Init(_DeviceCode, 0, 0, BASSWASAPIInit.BASS_WASAPI_BUFFER, 1f, 0.05f, _WasapiProcess, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (!result)
        {
            throw new BassWasapiInitException(Bass.BASS_ErrorGetCode().ToString());
        }

        BassWasapi.BASS_WASAPI_Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }


    ~SpectrumBeatDetector()
    {
        // Kill working thread and clean after BASS
        if(_AnalysisThread != null && _AnalysisThread.IsAlive)
        {
            _AnalysisThread.Abort();
        }

        Free();
    }

    // Sensivity Setters
    public void SetBassSensivity(SensivityLevel Sensivity)
    {
        _BASSSensivity = Sensivity;
    }

    public void SetMidsSensivity(SensivityLevel Sensivity)
    {
        _MIDSSensivity = Sensivity;
    }

    #endregion

    #region BASS-dedicated Methods

    // WASAPI callback, required for continuous recording
    private static int Process(IntPtr buffer, int length, IntPtr user)
    {
        return length;
    }

    // Cleans after BASS
    public void Free()
    {
        BassWasapi.BASS_WASAPI_Free();
        Bass.BASS_Free();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Analysis public methods

    // Starts a new Analysis Thread
    public void StartAnalysis()
    {
        // Kills currently running analysis thread if alive
        if (_AnalysisThread != null && _AnalysisThread.IsAlive)
        {
            _AnalysisThread.Abort();
        }

        // Starts a new high-priority thread
        _AnalysisThread = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    //Stopwatch SW = new Stopwatch();
                    //SW.Start();
                    Thread.Sleep(5);
                    PerformAnalysis();
                    //SW.Stop();
                    //Console.WriteLine(SW.Elapsed);
                }
            });

        _AnalysisThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        _AnalysisThread.Start();
    }

    // Kills running thread
    public void StopAnalysis()
    {
        if(_AnalysisThread != null && _AnalysisThread.IsAlive)
        {
            _AnalysisThread.Abort();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Event handling

    public void Subscribe(BeatDetectedHandler Delegate)
    {
        OnDetected += Delegate;
    }

    public void UnSubscribe(BeatDetectedHandler Delegate)
    {
        OnDetected -= Delegate;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Analysis private methods

    // Shifts history n places to the right
    private void ShiftHistory(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < BANDS; i++)
        {
            for (int j = HISTORY - 1 - n; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                _History[i, j + n] = _History[i, j];
            }
        }
    }

    // Performs FFT analysis in order to detect beat
    private void PerformAnalysis()
    {
        // Specifes on which result end which band (dividing it into 10 bands)
        // 19 - bass, 187 - mids, rest is highs
        int[] BandRange = { 4, 8, 18, 38, 48, 94, 140, 186, 466, 1022, 22000};
        double[] BandsTemp = new double[BANDS];
        int n = 0;
        int level = BassWasapi.BASS_WASAPI_GetLevel();

        // Get FFT
        int ret = BassWasapi.BASS_WASAPI_GetData(_FFTData, (int)BASSData.BASS_DATA_FFT1024 | (int)BASSData.BASS_DATA_FFT_COMPLEX); //get channel fft data
        if (ret < -1) return;

        // Calculate the energy of every result and divide it into subbands
        float sum = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i < 2048; i = i + 2)
        {
            float real = _FFTData[i];
            float complex = _FFTData[i + 1];
            sum += (float)Math.Sqrt((double)(real * real + complex * complex));

            if(i == BandRange[n])
            {
                BandsTemp[n++] = (BANDS * sum) / 1024;
                sum = 0;
            }
        }

        // Detect beat basing on FFT results
        DetectBeat(BandsTemp, level);

        // Shift the history register and save new values
        ShiftHistory(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < BANDS; i++)
        {
            _History[i, 0] = BandsTemp[i];
        }
    }

    // Calculate the average value of every band
    private double[] CalculateAverages()
    {
        double[] avg = new double[BANDS];

        for (int i = 0; i < BANDS; i++)
        {
            double sum = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < HISTORY; j++)
            {
                sum += _History[i, j];
            }

            avg[i] = (sum / HISTORY);
        }

        return avg;
    }

    // Detects beat basing on analysis result
    // Beat detection is marked on the first three bits of the returned value
    private byte DetectBeat(double[] Energies, int volume)
    {
        // Sound height ranges (1, 2 is bass, next 6 is mids)
        int Bass = 3;
        int Mids = 6;

        double[] avg = CalculateAverages();
        byte result = 0;
        double volumelevel = (double)volume / 32768 * 100;   // Volume level in %

        for (int i = 0; i < BANDS && result == 0; i++)                    
        {
            // Set the C parameter
            double C = 0;

            if (i < Bass)
            {
                C = 2.3 * ((double)_BASSSensivity / 100);
            }
            else if (i < Mids)
            {
                C = 2.89 * ((double)_MIDSSensivity / 100);
            }
            else
            {
                C = 3 * ((double)_MIDSSensivity / 100);
            }

            // Compare energies in all bands with C*average
            if(Energies[i] > (C * avg[i]) && volumelevel > 1)   // Second rule is for noise reduction
            {
                byte res = 0;
                if(i<Bass)
                {
                    res = 1;
                }
                else if (i < Mids)
                {
                    res = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    res = 4;
                }
                result = (byte)(result | res);
            }
        }

        if(result > 0)
        {
            OnDetected(result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    #endregion

}
}
```

Comment: Does it work? Does it recognize beats?

Comment: It depends on a song and a source (works really well with Spotify, a bit worse with YouTube) but as far as I checked it recognized beats in most of the songs I tested it on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Naming**

Based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) input parameters should be named using `camelCase` casing.

Although it isn't mentioned in the guidelines, you should consider to use the same casing for variables which are local to a method.

You have a lot of magic numbers in your code which should be extracted to well named constants. In this way **Mr.Maintainer** wouldn't have to think to much about them.

If you need a comment to know what a variable is about, then this variable is poorly named.

**General**

- Comments should describe **why** something is done. Let the code itself tell **what** is done by using meaningful names.
- commented code is dead code which should be removed
- leave your variables some space to breathe. `if(i < Bass)` is more readable than `if(i<Bass)`.

**DetectBeat()**

You don't need to assign `0` to the `C` variable, because an assignment changing this value is happening anyhow.

If the condition `if(Energies[i] > (C * avg[i]) && volumelevel > 1)` evaluates to true, you can break out of the `for` loop instead of again checking the `for` conditions.

By extracting the calculating of the `C` parameter into a separate method, the `DetectBeat()` method will be reduced to its core responsibility.

```
private const int _Bass = 3;
private const int _Mids = 6;
private double CalculateCParameter(int band)
{
    if (band < _Bass)
    {
        return C = 2.3 * ((double)_BASSSensivity / 100);
    }
    if (band < _Mids)
    {
        return 2.89 * ((double)_MIDSSensivity / 100);
    }
    return C = 3 * ((double)_MIDSSensivity / 100);
}
```

And by extracting the calculation of the result to a separate method

```
private byte CalculateResultByBand(int band)
{
    if(band < _Bass)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (i < _Mids)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    return 4;
}
```

the `DetectBeat()` method can, after adding a guard clause for `volumelevel <= 1` be simplified to

```
private byte DetectBeat(double[] Energies, int volume)
{

    double[] avg = CalculateAverages();
    byte result = 0;
    double volumelevel = (double)volume / 32768 * 100;   // Volume level in %

    if (volumelevel <= 1) { return result;}

    for (int i = 0; i < BANDS && result == 0; i++)                    
    {
        // Set the C parameter
        double C = CalculateCParameter(i);
        // Compare energies in all bands with C*average
        if(Energies[i] > (C * avg[i]))   
        {
            result = CalculateResultByBand(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(result > 0)
    {
        OnDetected(result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Free() versus `IDisposable`**

Because you are having unmanaged resources you really should implement `IDisposable` to free the unmanaged resources.

Read more about disposing finalizable types here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  (scroll down)